# How do I insert a node in linked list at 0th position using a custom method?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created a method to insert a node in LinkedList at **Nth** index. The code works fine for all the positions except 0th position. Please review my code below and let me know what's wrong.
The below code has 2 insert methods:

1. `insert(int data)`: This used to add a new node.
2. `insertAtNthPositon(int position, int data)`: This helps to insert the element at Nth position.

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        Node new_node = new Node();
        new_node.data = data;
        new_node.next = null;

        if (head == null) {
            head = new_node;
        } else {
            Node n = head;
            while (n.next != null) {
                n = n.next;
            }
            n.next = new_node;
        }
    }

    public void insertAtNthPositon(int position, int data) {
        Node new_node = new Node();
        new_node.data = data;
        Node current_node = head;

        int i = 0;
        if (position == 0) {
            new_node.next = current_node.next;
            head = new_node;
            current_node = current_node.next;
        }
        while (i < position - 1) {
            current_node = current_node.next;
            i++;
        }
        new_node.next = current_node.next;
        current_node.next = new_node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        LinkedList ls = new LinkedList();
        ls.insert(6);
        ls.insert(7);
        ls.insert(9);
        ls.insertAtNthPositon(1, 100);
        ls.show();

    }

    private void show() {
        Node current = head;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            sb.append(current.data);
            sb.append("->");
            current = current.next;
        } while (current != null);
        sb.append("null");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

> 6->100->7->9->null

Comment: There are some variables/parameters you haven't defined and the top of your code starts in the middle of a method.  Is that the insert(..) or insertAtNthPosition(..) method?  What is the difference between these two methods?  Perhaps you don't need both and you only need one method (they seem to do the same thing)?  Are you actually using java.util.LinkedList ?  Last I checked it doesn't have insert methods.

Comment: As mentioned above, some details are missing, but in here:
 new_node.next = current_node.next, I think  new_node.next should point to current_node instead of  current_node.next

Comment: If `head` is initialized to `null`, then this line: `new_node.next = current_node.next;` will generate an NPE.  You need to provide more in your code above to tell us what you're doing to determine why 0 is failing as an index for your homework assignment. Otherwise, you should be using `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: Just made some edits to the code for more clarity.

Comment: Just as I suggested: you need to set the new_node.next to current_node and not current_node.next -> this is why you always start from index 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I suggested: you need to set [at: if (position == 0)]  the new_node.next to current_node and not current_node.next -> this is why you always start from index 1 and not 0.

```
   public void insertAtNthPositon(int position, int data){
    Node new_node = new Node();
    new_node.data =data;
    Node current_node = head;

    int i = 0;
    if (position == 0){
        **new_node.next = current_node;** <instead of current_node.next>
        head = new_node;
        current_node = current_node.next;
    }
    while(i < position - 1){
        current_node = current_node.next;
        i++;
    }
    new_node.next = current_node.next;
    current_node.next = new_node;
}
```

BTW-  ls.insertAtNthPositon(1, 100); insert 100 at index 1, you want to do  ls.insertAtNthPositon(0, 100); in order for '100' to be the first.

Comment: When the list is empty and `insertAtNthPosition(0, data)` is invoked, you'll still get an NPE at `current_node = current_node.next;` inside the block for `if (position == 0)`.  Also, there's no need to perform the instructions after the `while` loop if `position` is `0`, in fact, `new_node.next = current_node.next;` and the next line at the end will result in memory leaks (2 Nodes to be specific).  You'll need to remove those 2 lines or guard them in an `if` block.